# Cannot use @NotBlank

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just started working with spring and I'm trying to use @NotBlank. Problem is it is not working. In pom.xml I have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The error I'm getting is this:
[image]

This is my import:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
```

and I'm also getting this error:

[image]

I have searched similar questions and the answer is that by adding this dependency and restarting IDE will work. In my case it's still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: is the package available? Did you write the import? Did you refresh the maven dependencies in IntelliJ? -> There should be a `Maven` tab situated in the top right of the editor. There should be two arrows in a circle, click that and you will (re)import the dependencies.

Comment: Please show your import statement for `NotBlank`.

Comment: @Lino I wrote the import and also refreshed maven dependencies. Still not working.

Comment: This is my import ' import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank; ' @Paul

Comment: Add a dependency on [javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final](https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/jar).

Comment: I replaced my dependency with the apache Maven dependency in the link you gave me but I still cant import validation. Still Cannot resolve symbol 'validation'. @Paul

Comment: I didn't say to replace your dependency; I said to add a dependency. [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.7.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.7.0/jar) has a dependency on [org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.2.3.Final](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.2.3.Final/jar) which we use on my project at work (where I am right now) and had to import `validation-api` to use. At the very least I would expect you'd get a different error after importing it.

Comment: @Paul  I downloaded the .jar file and added it from File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> '+' -> Jars or Directories. Thank you for your time and help! :)

Comment: That's great, glad it worked! I consolidated my comments into an answer; please accept if you feel I adequately described the solution.

Comment: You really should add the dependency in pom.xml instead of adding it as a downloaded jar in your ide.

Comment: @KristofNeirynck It could be that adding the dependency that way modifies the pom but I don't know.  I use NetBeans which is not what OP is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dependency on [javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final](https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/jar). That defines the validation API (i.e. the interface) but does not implement it.  [spring-boot-starter-validation](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.7.0/jar) has a dependency on [hibernate-validator](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.2.3.Final/jar) which is the reference implementation of Java's validation API.

You imported the implementation but not the interface which is why your IDE was complaining.  By importing both the interface and the implementation that code should compile.